# Lookup value (DAX) in from table to find missing records

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking to get this idea in PowerBI, and hope someone can help me.

Table 1 is the main data where contains all the name. I have another table (table 2) that have all the login/logout. My outcome desire is to find who is missing from table 1. so we can keep record.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to create a calculated table.

```
No Login Tracking = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 'Table2'[Date], 'Table1'[Name] ),
        CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table2' ) ) = 0
    ),
    "Status", "Missing"
)
```

[image]